# Azure Web Apps Reverse Proxy based on Hostname

Tags: azure, iis, proxy, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App (formerly Azure Websites) running a Node application based on Hapi.js. Hapi runs three different applications on three different ports. Locally, I'm running nginx and have 3 different domains each point to a different port using `proxy_pass`:

```
api.business.mywebsite.com --> localhost:3001
api.customer.mywebsite.com --> localhost:3002
api.admin.mywebsite.com --> localhost:3003
```

Ideally, I'd like to have a similar setup on my Azure Web App where the Hapi server is running on ports 3001-3003 and based on the incoming hostname (ex: `api.business.mywebsite.com`), which points to `mywebsite.azurewebsites.net`, would proxy to the port where that particular application is running. I've read [this article](https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/) as well as a few others, but I'm still not quite sure a) if it's possible and b) how to configure it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rereading your question, why do you want to setup reverse proxies like this? Why not just make those domains point directly to the destination you want?  I'm not seeing what you gain by using reverse proxies

Comment: I'm not sure how I would be able to do that. This is a single node application that serves on three different ports. Essentially, the application mounts a specific set of routes per port. It's not that I want to redirect to a different site entirely, I just want to be able to point to a specific port internally based on where the request originated. So for example, I'd point `api.business.mywebsite.com` to `mywebsite.azurewebsites.net`, it would look at the request origin and see `api.business.mywebsite.com` and then forward that request to the application on port 3001.

Comment: Why do you want to route the request to different ports? What does that give you?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I have an application that serves up limited-access APIs, but with a shared codebase, on three different ports. If it's not possible to do within Azure Web Apps, that's fine -- I can change my approach, but just looking for a definitive answer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Nope, it's not possible to open up different ports on Azure Web Apps.  And for your desired usage I suspect there are much better options available to you than opening up ports to redirect traffic

Comment: Thanks, Zain. Just to be clear, I'm not asking to open up ports to the outside world, I want to forward traffic to a specific port internally based on the origin. This is already happening as I set my `PORT` environment variable and then Azure is forwarding the port 80/443 traffic to that port. Again, I'm just looking to do it for more than one port based on the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions on how to create a reverse proxy: http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/

These are the key steps:

### 1. Enable Reverse Proxy on your site

Create an applicationHost.xdt file in your sites folder with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">  
  <system.webServer>  
    <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" />  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

### 2. Add your rewrite rules to your web.config file:

Example rule:

```
<configuration>  
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
      <rules>  
        <rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">  
          <match url="^proxyUrl/?(.*)" />  
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.iis.net/{R:1}" />  
        </rule>  
      </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

To make the reverse proxy be based on the host name, just set the appropriate match url

Comment: Thank you, Zain. For the <action> url, would I use something like 'localhost:3001' or the full Azure Websites domain (ex: mywebsite.azurewebsites.net:3001/{R:1})?

Comment: You can't open up specific ports (like port 3001) on Azure Web Apps. I had thought you would redirect the request to some other site.